# Return last log per each day - Rails 7 (PostgreSql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model - `Account` which `has_many :totals`; `Total` is another model with a callback to generate a new log each time a transaction has been made. I would like to display the last total record per each day and make a graph for the given ranges (ex. last 7 days, 1 month, 6 months, etc.);

```
Example:

total yesterday: 2312 (the last yesterday's total record)
total today: 2400 (the today's total record)
```

I've done some research and found a lot of different answers but none of them gave me the right results. I want to avoid loops and return data in the most performant way.

I use Ruby on Rails 7 and PostgreSQL. Can someone please explain how to get that result?

PS: I use `UUIDs` instead of regular `ID`. Based on the research, a lot of people use IDs for sorting.

---

**UPDATE:**

Current solution

```rb
list = ::Total.where(account: current_account).select("max(created_at) as created_at").group("date_trunc('day', created_at)")

totals = ::Total.where(created_at: list)
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, I have taken the approach in similar situations to cache the result (in your case that would be the last total record each day) in a separate database table. It doesn't make sense (to me) to recalculate the same value over and over, each time you wish to generate the graphs... once the day has passed the total for that day never changes (I assume, right?).

So every time you generate a graph for a date range, pull cached "total" values from the db and calculate only values that aren't cached (storing them in the db for next time).

This approach prevents the query from getting slower and slower as the days and months pass.

So you might have a new model `DayTotal` which `belongs_to :account` and Account `has_many :day_totals`. The columns in the day_totals table would be date, total and account_id.